# ClamTK gives wrong warning?

Tags: netbeans, clamav

I scanned my computer using ClamTK and it reported several threats, but most of the files it indicated as threats are files from my Netbeans IDE.(highly trustable source)

Are my Netbeans files really infected or ClamTK gives wrong warning?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and properly update regularly with important security updates.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of infection is W32.Packer.MingwGCC-2. Mingw is a compiler after seen on Cygwin for Windows (Minimalist GNU for Windows). I'd say it's trustable.

I haven't been able to locate any information on why this is considered an infections. My best guess though is that it's just a warning because it's packing code (packers allow obfuscation of the code as well as a way to possibly avoid detection from antiviruses - though it has practical uses too).

Edit:
See [this page](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/faq/pua/) on the ClamAV site, specifically the section on Packers. It explains what a packer is.

Comment: I found out that the PUA part means "Potentially Unwanted Applications." I've seen PUA show up on stuff like netsend (a legitimate program).